# Problema con CORS vue.js y php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, vue.js, cors

Buen día gente!
Les quería hacer una consulta para ver si alguien me puede dar una mano. Estoy desarrollando un sitio con vue de forma local y tengo hosteado los archivos php que realizan las acciones a la base de datos y la base de datos en 000webhost (esto por solo práctica y requerimiento de la facultad).
El problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo un sistema de login y en firefox me tira el error: Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://librotecafinal.000webhostapp.com/acciones/auth.iniciar-sesion.php. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null).

Error en la solicitud: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
y en google Chrome: POST https://librotecafinal.000webhostapp.com/acciones/auth.iniciar-sesion.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Desde donde me conecto de modo local sería acá: http://localhost:8080/#/iniciar-sesion
Y el componente es el siguiente:

```js
<template>
    <v-form v-on:submit.prevent="login" novalidate>
        <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            v-model.trim="email"
        >
        </v-text-field>
        <span v-show="enviado===true && !email"><svg-icon type="mdi" :path="path"></svg-icon>El email es requerido.</span>
        <v-text-field
            label="Contraseña"
            v-model.trim="password"
        >
        </v-text-field>
        <span v-show="enviado===true && !password"><svg-icon type="mdi" :path="path"></svg-icon>La contraseña es requerida.</span>
        <v-btn
            type="submit"
        >
        Iniciar sesión
        </v-btn>
    </v-form>
</template>

<script>
import SvgIcon from '@jamescoyle/vue-icon';
import { mdiAlertCircle } from '@mdi/js';

export default{
    name: 'ComponenteLogin',
    components:{
        SvgIcon,
    },
    data: function(){
        return{
            email: "",
            password: "",
            enviado: false,
            path: mdiAlertCircle
        }
    },
    methods:{
        login:function(){
            //let data = [];
            this.enviado = true;

            if(this.email && this.password){
                let data = {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                }
                
                fetch('https://librotecafinal.000webhostapp.com/acciones/auth.iniciar-sesion.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    credentials: 'omit',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if(data.success){
                        alert(data.message);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error en la solicitud:', error);
                })

                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Y estoy tratando de acceder al archivo: auth.iniciar-sesion.php que está hosteado:

```js
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // Indica los métodos permitidos.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE');
    // Indica los encabezados permitidos.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
    http_response_code(204);
}

use Auth\Autenticacion;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/init.php';

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

$autenticacion = new Autenticacion();

if(!$autenticacion->iniciarSesion($email, $password)){
    $response = [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'El email o clave ingresada no son correctos.'
    ];
} else {
    $response = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Inicio de sesión exitoso.'
    ];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Le agregué también en el archivo ".htaccess" que figura en la carpeta "public_html" de 000WebHost lo siguiente:

```js
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
# HTID:22561993: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:22561993:
```

Pero aún así me sigue tirando el mismo error. ¿Qué mas puedo hacer para solucionar esto? ¿Alguien puede darme una mano?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes que habilitar CORS en tu back...